# replace using javascript regex outside a special tag?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace (remove) html tags outside the [code] bbcode using javascript. for example:

```
 <script>these</script> [code]<script>alert</script>[/code]<script>that</script>
```

should become

```
 these [code]<script>alert</script>[/code]that
```

how use RegEx to replace/remove tags outside [code]?

Comment: Can't you simply disable HTML for your site/forum's posts or something? Seems like you're trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Also, if you're trying to prevent malicious-code, this should be done server-side and not client side. Sanitization must be done server-side.

Comment: no use it in WYSIWYG editor. I want to display html codes within [code] tag in editor (no server-side submition exist)

Comment: Oh I see. Many editors have sanitization options/plugins as well. If you include which one you're using in the question, it might be easier to find an answer.

Comment: it's tinymce with a customized bbcode plugnin. customized bbcode plugin strip out html tags at the moment. I want extend it to strip out htmls outside [code] tags.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

ok I find a solution:

```
replace(/<(?=[^\[]*\[\/code\])/gi,"&_lt_;");
replace(/>(?=[^\[]*\[\/code\])/gi,"&_gt_;");

DO OTHER REPLACEMENT/CUSTOMIZATION HERE

replace(/&_lt_;/gi,"<");
replace(/&_gt_;/gi,">");
```

that it! :)

Answer (score 3):

Replace this `/(\[code\][\s\S]*?\[\/code\])|<[\s\S]*?>/g` to `$1`:

```
your_string.replace(/(\[code\][\s\S]*?\[\/code\])|<[\s\S]*?>/g, '$1');
```

It'll find all `[code]` tags first, save them, and after that it will find the remaining html tags (which will *not* be in the `[code]` tags).

Comment: could you please explain more with an example? I do not get it

Comment: I just get it but problem is that I should replace < and > with &lt; &gt; at the same time.

Comment: Didn't get. You have to erase both `<tag>` and `&lt;tag&gt;` outside the [code]? Or `<...>` inside the [code] replace to `&lt;...&gt;`?

Comment: nevermind let say this way: I want to replace < within [code] tag with something like *, it will help me do the main job. what's the best regexp for that? (replacing < within [code] tags). and of course same thing for <

Comment: If you do my regexp first, all pair `<` and `>` would be in the [code] tag. So you can run two another replaces after.

Comment: @daftcoder Can you please update this fiddle with that `$1` ? http://jsfiddle.net/jRRxY/   I am also interested to make it work. Thanks :)

Comment: @Stano [Chech that](http://jsfiddle.net/jRRxY/4/). Pay attention on JQuery text, it escapes html tags that are in the resulting string.

Comment: @daftcoder Thanks, I started thinking about using the match() function, but your solution is perfect. And btw, jQuery can be easily omitted here, [look at this little mod](http://jsfiddle.net/jRRxY/5/) writes the same :-) Thanks again and +1 for you :)

Comment: @Stano yeah, nice =) I'm not much experienced in document properties, thanks for that solution!